# Common Name for CA-Signed CSR in MTLS?

Tags: apex, soap, certificates, ssl, tls

I am trying to set up MTLS for my client->server SOAP Apex callout to an external web app, following the directions in these help articles:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_soap.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&language=en_US&type=5

**What I'm confused about is what I should set as the Common Name on my Certificate Signing Request.** According to the documentation I should use the FQDN of my business, but the traffic is being sent from my Salesforce org, so I am confused about whether my business's domain would be valid in this scenario. Could anyone provide guidance?

Comment: That's just a suggestion. Use whatever makes sense to your CA and the target endpoint.

Comment: Hi @identigral, thanks for your response. I think I'm missing something about the purpose of the Common Name in MTLS. I checked my certificate authority's requirements, and they say: "The Common Name field should be the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) or the Web address for which you plan to use your Certificate". 

Is it correct then that it doesn't need to match my Salesforce domain, and I should just use my business's FQDN?

I had thought that the Common Name needed to match the source of my API traffic, but maybe this was a misconception.

Comment: Having CN be the FQDN is a common practice but ultimately it's up to your target endpoint and CA. If they don't validate it, anything goes.